# topological Euler characteristic of canonical divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex smooth projective variety with trivial topological Euler characteristic $\chi_{\text{top}}(X)=0$. We assume that $D$ is a smooth irreducible divisor in the linear system $|K_X|$ of the canonical divisor $K_X$ of $X$. Is  $\chi_{\text{top}}(D)=0$?

Comment: What happens if you consider the blow-up at 4 points of the product $C \times C \times C$, where $C$ is a smooth curve of genus $2$?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi  Thank you for your example!

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi.  Why is there a smooth irreducible divisor in the canonical linear system of that blowing up?

Comment: @JasonStarr: Actually, I do not know whether it exists. It is part of my "What happens..."

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi: it doesn't exist. The canonical system of the blown-up variety has a fixed part, namely the 4 exceptional divisors.

Comment: @abx: you are clearly right. I realized this as soon as I took paper and pencil :)

Comment: In fact, this approach only works in the case where the variety that we blow-up has trivial canonical class. So, for instance, we might look for a Calabi-Yau threefold $Y$ with $\chi_{\operatorname{top}}(Y)=-2$ and blow-up it at a point (this is the strategy of Sasha's answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. Consider, for instance a Calabi--Yau threefold $Y$ with $h^{2,1}(Y) = h^{1,1}(Y) + 1$ (an example of such can be found in https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.06303, see page 29) and let $X$ be the blowup of $Y$ in a point. Then $\chi_{\mathrm{top}}(X) = 0$, but the canonical class of $X$ is equal to the exceptional divisor of the blowup, hence the (unique) canonical divisor is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your conterexample.